# htaccess file, merge two sets of rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi and I appreciate anyone who can help me with this mod_rewrite code. I am just very unfamiliar with writing htaccess from scratch so any help would be great.

I am using this code to organize my root dir, by allowing me to place the files for my main domain in a subduer:

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?kinetic-designs.net$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kd/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kd/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?kinetic-designs.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ kd/index.html [L]
```

Now in order to use the CDN my host provides I need to ensure that my domain is being loaded at http://www.example.net and not example.net. So they say to use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This doesn't work because I'm pretty sure it conflict wit the code above. Any one have a suggestion on how to modify the top block of code to include the lower block rules?

Or if you know a good resource to learn about how these rules actually work, i had trouble finding quality docs on the subject.

Thanks again! : )

Comment: Actually the second rule set does the opposit of what you comment to it.

Comment: really? it would rewrite the domain to only example.net?

Comment: Well yes, just read it: If the condition matches, that the requested host is "www.yourdomain.com", then redirect externally to host "yourdomain.com". That means that if someone types "www.yourdomain.com" into his browser, then it will be altered to "yourdomain.com". Not more, not less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@arkascha was correct, switching the order of that rule worked.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kinetic-designs.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.kinetic-designs.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```